# How to order some column by some values of string in JPA

Tags: mysql, jpa

I'm trying to ORDER BY the strings values.

```
For example string column is:
dog
cat
bird
fish
...
```

and im tring to order them by my order for example I like it to first present the fishes and then the dogs and then the cats etc.

MySQL has a function called field but it doesnt work in JPA or im writing it wrong

```
SELECT 
  a 
FROM Animal a 
ORDER BY 
  FIELD(a.type, 'fish','dog','cat','bird')
```

can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Could you show the entity class for a pet?

Comment: its generated from netbeans automatically it has 2 columns 2 strings first is the name second is the kind and i would like to show the results from a table ordered by some order of kinds of animals. I would like to show all dogs then all fishes then all cats then all birds for example

Answer (score 0):

JPQL (JPA 2.1) has `"FUNCTION"` which can be used to invoke any SQL function in the RDBMS.

Comment: how can i do that? can you type me an example?

Comment: Just read the docs of your JPA implementation, perhaps. I use http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jpa/jpql.html#functions

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

SELECT 
  a 
FROM Animal a 
ORDER BY 
  type='fish' DESC, type='dog' DESC, type='cat' DESC, type='bird' DESC;